# if statement returning false for unknown reason

Tags: java, arrays, swing, boolean, cyrillic

I posted a question a few minutes ago and it was requested that I post an "SSCCE" to demonstrate my issue. I have heavily condensed my program so if a few constructs make no sense or seem even more ineffcient than a novice's work ought to be that's simply a product of that operation.

Now, my program essentially serves to copy an array of Russian verbs conjugations to a centralized array, *oneRay*. In the setup here, a prompt is shown above a blank line, and in that blank line one is to type the appropriate conjugation. Pressing the "Submit" button is **supposed** to check the answers against those of the array, but by my own fault or lack of understanding I see the message "FAIL" even when directly copying what I know to be the correct answer. With this line I get the input:

```
build1 = new StringBuilder(ssfield1.getText());
```

and with this I check it against the element:

```
if(build1.equals(oneRay[pick][1].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","")))ssfield1.setText("CORRECT");
    else{ssfield1.setText("FAIL");}
```

I feel that this may be a simple issue of checking the wrong element against the wrong input textfield, however it mayn't be, so here is all the code of my condensed "SSCCE":

Not to long I hope, and certainly self-contained (and quite simple too):
Let me know if you need anything else, or if it's too late for these questions!

```
package wbh;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class SwingImplementation_RUS extends JFrame{
String [] [] oneRay;Random random = new Random();
JPanel panel; JTextField field,sfield1,sfield2,ssfield1,ssfield2; JButton buton;
int pick, hold;StringBuilder build1,build2;
public SwingImplementation_RUS(final int subj){
    super("To be updated"); 
    final String RUS_1[][]={
        {"знать","знаю","знаешь","знает","знает","знает","знаем","знаете","знают",}};
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                buton = new JButton("Submit");
                setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,3,3));
                panel = new JPanel();panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,3,3));
                field = new JTextField();
                sfield1 = new JTextField("Я");sfield2 = new JTextField("Ты");
                ssfield1 = new JTextField("");ssfield2 = new JTextField("");

                buton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent m) {
                        System.out.println("CHECKED");
                        build1 = new StringBuilder(ssfield1.getText());
                        build2 = new StringBuilder(ssfield2.getText());
                        called2();}}); 

                Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 75);
                field.setFont(f);

                add(field);
                add(panel);
                panel.add(sfield1);panel.add(ssfield1);
                panel.add(sfield2);panel.add(ssfield2);
                add(buton);
                setLocation(500,0);setSize(865, 700);
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);setVisible(true);
                }}).start();

                oneRay = new String[RUS_1.length][9];
               for(int i = 0; (RUS_1.length) > i; i++){
                   oneRay[i][0] = RUS_1[i][0];oneRay[i][1] = RUS_1[i][1];
                   oneRay[i][2] = RUS_1[i][2];} 

        try {Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        hold = oneRay.length;pick = random.nextInt(hold);
        field.setText("                 "+oneRay[pick][0]); 
}
private void called2(){
    if(build1.equals(oneRay[pick][1].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","")))ssfield1.setText("CORRECT");
    else{ssfield1.setText("FAIL");}
    if(build2.equals(oneRay[pick][2].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s","")))ssfield2.setText("CORRECT");
    else{ssfield2.setText("FAIL");}

}
public static void main (String [] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
        new SwingImplementation_RUS(1);
        } 
    });
}
```

}

Comment: You are using the `equals`method of a StringBuilder against a String. I guess that's the error. Try `ssfield1.getText().equals(...)`

Comment: @Fildor +1, try to use build1.toString().equals

Comment: @IlyaBursov You are right, that should be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using `StringBuilder#equals` and expected it to work like `String#equals`.

The implementation of equals for `StringBuilder` looks like...

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Which is just comparing the object references, not there contents.

Instead, try using something like...

```
if (build1.toString().equals(oneRay[pick][1].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""))) ...
```

As a recommendation, you should also use `{}` around your `if-else` conditions, for example

```
if (build1.toString().equals(oneRay[pick][1].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""))) {
    ssfield1.setText("CORRECT");
} else {
    ssfield1.setText("FAIL");
}
if (build2.toString().equals(oneRay[pick][2].toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s", ""))) {
    ssfield2.setText("CORRECT");
} else {
    ssfield2.setText("FAIL");
}
```

Which will make it easier to read (generally) and ensure that you are not accidently executing functionality you didn't expect for a condition...

Comment: I'll accept this as soon as it will let me. Thank you, this was my first ever use of a StringBuilder. You have made my day!

Comment: `StringBuilder` is an incredibly useful class, it's just not a `String`...that's kind of the point ;)